# What is the solubility of rotenone in ethanol?

Tags: cell-culture

I’m trying to kill SH-SY5Y cells with rotenone, but the rotenone does not kill. I saw an article where rotenone is soluble at 5mM in ethanol. I dissolved 1.7 mg in 1 ml of ethanol to obtain a 1ml of 5mM solution. I also tried DMSO but it’s viscous when dissolved in DMEM. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: How much DMSO are you adding to how much volume of media?

Comment: Also, your solution is only 4.3 mM, not 5. Please [edit] your question and add more details, including how old your rotenone stock is and how it's been stored, how old the solutions are and how they've been stored, the concentration you're using to kill the SH-SY5Y cells, how long after the addition of rotenone you're waiting before checking for cell death, and the manner in which you are looking for cell death.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This sort of question, although related to practical biology, is not really suitable for this site, because it is, in effect, a question about the properties of a molecule that anyone can find by searching the web. And if you finish the [Tour] and read the Help on asking questions you will see that this is what we expect from posters. I know nothing about rotenone, am not familiar with organic chemistry databases, but was able to find that NCBI has a PubChem site documenting compounds. Look here: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Rotenone#section=NSC-Number .

Comment: Actually, as written, it looks more like a Chemistry.SE question.